# Open Geany Template with Shortcut

Tags: 20.04, geany

To open the geany template file manually, we need to follow the following steps,

File -> New(with Template) -> main.c(or other programming language template)

Can I make a shortcut(possibly keybindings) to do the things automatically ? I am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geany does not provide a command line interface to open new files bases on a template. Directly creating a shortcut that launches Geany that way therefore may not be possible

You could work around with the Template system of the standard Gnome desktop. Link the template of Geany you want to be easily accessible into your "~/Templates" directory. Create that directory if it does not exist.

Then you can create a new document based on the template using the "Templates" entry in the right-click menu (clicking on an empty part of the folder). You can also summon that right-click menu with the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Thus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> will allow you to select the template. A new document, which is a copy of the template, is placed in your folder. You can then rename it and launch it in Geany.

Comment: Can I do something with terminal ?

Comment: Actually this is not what I am looking for.I want to do it directly from geany but as you have mentioned that this is not possible at all, I am accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a keybinding or add a sortcut, but the drop down arrow next to the "new" icon, takes you straight there.